# ZOOM API Ouath 2.0 -> Invalid access token error is coming in karate framework

Tags: karate, zoom-sdk

I am trying to use oauth 2.0 token in karate framework for zoom API. I followed the ouath2.0 example from karate doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature

```
    Given url 'https://zoom.us'
    And path '/oauth/token'
    * form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'  --> This need to update as zoom does not support password
    * form field username = 'my email id'
    * form field password = 'my password'
    * form field client_id = 'my client id'
    * form field client_secret = 'my client secret value'
    * method post
    * status 200
    * print response
    * def accessToken = response.access_token
```

When I hit this API, it creates the access token. When I use that access token in meeting api, it does not work. It says invalid access token.

```
Given url 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings' (Replaced me with userid also)
* header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
* method get
* status 200
```

Response:

```
{"code":200,"message":"Invalid api key or secret."}
```

Note: When I am using postman, I am providing callback_url as postman default redirect url

https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback

and check the option Authorize using browser.

Which I dont see here. Is that missing ?
If that is missing, then how can we add that part in karate?

Can someone please point what's missing here and what is the way to generate ouath 2.0 token for zoom api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one solution but looks like UI Automation needs to be integrated for this.
Purely from API, it looks like wouldn't work.

Steps:

1. Request User Authorization: This is used for generating the code.

   https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=yourclientId&redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback

This URL need to be hit in a java script based tool, otherwise you will get an error.

So to get this, you can launch this URL, in browser. It will ask you to do login.
Once authentication will be done, then it will change the URL to something like this:

```
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback?code=<one code value>
```

Once the code is generated, it can be used for generating token in step 2.

2: Request Access Token:

```
https://zoom.us/oauth/token?code=<Previously generated code>&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=<Using postman default one same as above>
```

In header, add "Authorization" value as

```
 Authorization: Basic base64Encode(client_id:client_secret)
```

In response, it returns, access_token. Which later can be reused for other api validations.

Comment: when you say `This URL need to be hit in a java script based tool` - what I would do is study the `Network` part of the browser developer tools. finally everything WILL boil down to a sequence of `GET` or `POST`s - which you can easily convert to a Karate script

Comment: Great  comment. I literally missed it for finishing it quickly and As I have the privilege to use UI Automation, so I moved that side. I would definitely replace that part. Thanks