# How to get access token using Karate oauth 2.0 Authorization implicit grant type

Tags: karate

I tried to automate using karate framework following steps which I did in postman.
How I tried in Postman:

1. On Authorization tab select OAuth 2.0
2. Select Header Prefix Bearer
3. Grant-Type is "Implicit"
4. I put Callback URL
5. I put Auth URL
6. I put Client ID
7. Select "Client Authentication" as Send as Basic Auth Header.

I used following code in order to get Access token
Background:

```
 * url 'Auth URL'

  Scenario: Verify the user details using OAuth2 Implicit grant type

    * form field callbackurl = 'callbackurl'
    * form field grant_type = 'implicit'
    * form field client_id = 'client id'
    * form field username = 'username'
    * form field password = 'password'
    * method post
    * status 200
    * print response

    * def accessToken = response.access_token

    * path 'resource'
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
# * param access_token = accessToken
    * method post
    * status 200
```

In output I got
// UserpoolId is not available on frontend for springboard. We do not use userPoolId
// anyway other than put in context data.
var userPoolId = "";
var clientId = getUrlParameter("client_id");

I do not know where I am wrong. Please provide your help. Thanks!

Comment: please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075964/143475 - and I can help if you can provide a working example that I can access on the public internet. else, please take the help of someone who knows the server-side in your case and also post an answer here if you solve it

Comment: @PeterThomas one off topic question,  can you please send me example how to use karate with GraphQL when we have Query like:  mutation($data: ParameterInput!){
    updateParameter(parameterInput: $data)
} and Graph Variables like {
    "data":{
        "id": 135,
        "name": "TimeoutSeconds",
        "value": 100,
        "routingKeyIds": [51]
    }

} Thank you!

Comment: read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360978/143475